# Disable rename of a file in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

When you click twice (not double click) on a file in JFileChooser, you can rename the selected file. How to disable this feature? I've tried with

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you do this before you created the `JFileChooser` instance?

Comment: @mre Yes, I did. I've putted It in a static block.

Comment: I've just tried this on my machine, setting the property works (I'm running JRE6). It also removes the "New Folder" button.

Comment: @BenvanGompel, So am I and it's not working for me..

Comment: It also works fine for me. I'm using JDK6_7 on XP. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem along with the version/platform you are using. That way others can then test your code on different platforms.

Comment: +1 to worksforme - OpenJDK 6 on Linux

Answer (score 12):

Surprisingly, you *cannot* disable renaming files/creating new directories from JFileChooser itself.  As you correctly surmised, you need to disable this FileChooser "feature" from UIManager instead.

Here's a snippet that might help:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/555535/GUI/java/FileChooser-readOnly

```
  Boolean old = UIManager.getBoolean("FileChooser.readOnly");  
  UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);  
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");  
  UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", old);
```

The key thing is to set "FileChooser.readOnly" BEFORE you create the file chooser.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, You're not able to edit the file name? All that happens for me is that I'm unable to create a new folder..wtf

Comment: @mre Yes, `UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);` works for me, and yes `new folder` option is gone too.

Comment: You can disable creating files via JFileChooser. Just use the JFileChooser(FileSystemView) constructor with an extension to javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView with empty implementations of createFileObject(...) and createNewFolder(...). This can also be used to stop users browsing to other locations etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Customizing a JFileChooser Look and Feel](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJFileChooserLookandFeel.htm) has some rename constants

Your static should go into the `JFileChooser` using class.

Alternatively do `addMouseListener` to throw click away.

Comment: What kind of mouse listener? I don't think mouse listener will be sufficient. Mybe with some kind of mouse event interceptor It'll work ?